# SQLAlchemy "'None' has no attribute 'label'"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

I've read all the other posts regarding enums and SQLAlchemy such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258376/array-of-enum-in-postgres-with-sqlalchemy) but when I create an example based on them I get the error `'None' has no attribute 'label'`. What is the error in the following code? I have no experience with Flask or SQLAlchemy so it may be something trivial.

I also tried using the custom ArrayOfEnum class and the `create_constraint=False, native_enum=False` parameters but that didn't help and there are real enums in my database anyways that I need to support.

When I just use an enum then it works without problems when I execute Flask-AppBuilder with `flask run` and open `http://127.0.0.1:5000/softwareproductview/add`. However it always crashes when using arrays of enums like this:

```
from flask_appbuilder import Model, Base
from enum import Enum
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql as pg
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Softwareproduct(Model):
    suffix = Column(String(200), primary_key=True)
    # jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'label'
    databasesystems =  Column(pg.ARRAY(sa.Enum("MySql","PostgreSql")))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    #databasesystems = Column(sa.Enum("MySql","PostgreSql")) # works
```

**Full Error**

```
2020-08-31 18:01:48,646:ERROR:app:Exception on /softwareproductview/add [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 109, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/views.py", line 588, in add
    return self.render_template(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 280, in render_template
    return render_template(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/add.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import 'appbuilder/general/lib.html' as lib %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends base_template %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/app/templates/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'appbuilder/baselayout.html' %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import 'appbuilder/baselib.html' as baselib %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/init.html", line 46, in top-level template code
    {% block body %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html", line 19, in block "body"
    {% block content %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/add.html", line 7, in block "content"
    {% block add_form %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/add.html", line 8, in block "add_form"
    {{ widgets.get('add')(form_action=form_action)|safe }}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/widgets.py", line 37, in __call__
    return template.render(args)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/widgets/form.html", line 45, in top-level template code
    {{ lib.render_field(field, begin_sep_label, end_sep_label, begin_sep_field, end_sep_field) }}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 679, in _invoke
    rv = self._func(*arguments)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/lib.html", line 230, in template
    {{ field.label.text }}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'label'
```

Comment: Can you post more details on this issue? Especially from the given directory `"/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/app/templates/base.html"`

Comment: @Ndrslmpk: Unfortunately this is too long ago and I remember nothing about this error anymore.